# Display an Angular Mat Card below Input Field and overlay all other div's

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am building a signup page where below the password field I want to display a mat card with password requirements with checkboxes.

I want to display the card on top of everything. Currently, the card pushes all other divs below (sign up button and whatnot). I do not want the card to shift around content. It should float on top of everything.

HTML:-

```
<div class="sign-in-box row">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sign-in-text">Sign Up</div>
  </div>
  <!-- input form -->
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div>
      <!-- Name Name -->
      <div class="input-field row">
        <div class="col">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="fName" required />
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="lName" required />
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- email -->
      <div class="input-field">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Email Address</mat-label>
          <input matInput formControlName="email" required />
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <!-- password -->
      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Password </mat-label>
          <input
            matInput
            [type]="hidePassword ? 'password' : 'text'"
            (focus)="onFocusChange()"
            (blur)="onFocusChange()"
            formControlName="password"
            required
          />
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <!-- Password hints -->
      <div *ngIf="showPasswordDetails" class="on-top">
        <mat-card>
          <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>Password Requirements</mat-card-title>
          </mat-card-header>
          <div>
            <mat-card-content>
              Password must contain 8 characters <br />
              Password must contain Upper Case Character <br />
              Password must contain Lower Case Character<br />
              Password must contain Number <br />
            </mat-card-content>
          </div>
          <mat-card-actions>
            <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
            <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
          </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- remember me box -->
    <mat-checkbox >Remember Me</mat-checkbox>

    <!-- Sign In Button -->
    <div class="sign-in-container">
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary">
        Sign In
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <!-- forgot password and signup -->
  <div class="forgot-password-signup">
    <a href="">Forgot Password?</a>
    <a href="">Dont Have an Account? Sign Up</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:-

```
.sign-in-box {
  margin: 5% 10%;
  height: 75%;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.icon-background {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f48fb1;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.icon-row {
  padding: 10px;
}

.sign-in-text {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.input-field {
  width: inherit;
  margin: 5% 0;
}

.sign-in-container {
  margin: 5% 0 0 0;
}

.forgot-password-signup {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.on-top {
  z-index: 100;
}

.width--inherit {
  width: inherit;
}
```

tried z index (Stackblitz below)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-wk73w3.io (please ignore the styling of components. Just fill in first name & last name, the email and password field will appear, and then when you click on the password field, you'll see the card pushes everything below when it appears)

any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem of `Z-index` , you have to set `Position` to `Fixed` to make it appear in top of the page's content

Try to make this change to your css block :

```
.on-top {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

i forked the project on stackblitz :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-pytrcz.io?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: you sir are a legend. Thanks a lot for the help;

Comment: if it's not too much trouble, I would like to ask a small extension to the current question, How do I make the width of the card div equal to the password field so that it looks neat. "width: fit-content" is too small and "width: inherit" is too large. no value width makes it the same as the input field width which I would also like to know why the behavior is this way after making the position: absolute if it's not too much to ask.